# Correlation between low altitude and dropping of final S?

Tags: pronunciación

In Mexico, I've noticed at an anecdotal level that people who tend to drop the final -S tend to be from areas of lower altitude.  This seems to fit with the idea that Caribbeans tend to drop the final -S.

Is there a known correlation with living at or close to sea level?

Comment: I've read somewhere that Andalusians speak faster and hence drop the final _s_ (among other letters) not because of altitude, but because of good weather that makes people more prone to be out in the streets and talking with other people. Along time that made people develop a faster and more economic way of speaking.

Comment: @Charlie vaya, que las _s_ finales son más de quedarse en casa :)

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the maps on [this source](https://sites.google.com/a/geneseo.edu/spanish-linguistics/spanish-phonology/aspiration-of-s) for the syllable-final S-dropping zones:

[image]

With these topographical maps showing the elevation of those regions:

[image]
[image]

There doesn't seem to be a strong correlation.

- While true for most of the Southern half of Spain, it doesn't hold for the Baetic mountains (Granada, Jaén), nor the Ebro river region, nor for the coast of the whole Northern half; and the difference between the Balearic and the Canary islands, with similar relief but different pronunciation, is also a big outlier.
- A similar thing happens in South America, where the whole Andes region (Chile, south of Argentina) is marked as S-dropping despite being very mountainous, while the inland parts of Colombia and Ecuador, being zones of low altitude, keep the S nonetheless.
- And the same goes for Central America for e.g. the Yucatan peninsula which, being one of the lowest regions of the whole Centroamerican isthmus, still pronounce the S.

As I said, I don't see a significant correlation between S-dropping and geographical altitude. There might or might not be some correlation with a warmer climate, but I'll leave that to [Charlie's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30737), since you only asked about the altitude.

Comment: En la Patagonia y Tierra del Fuego el clima no es precisamente conducente a quedarse charlando en la calle o en las plazas. El problema es que el poblamiento de esas áreas por gente que viene del centro de la zona rioplatense es históricamente reciente (y continúa); diría la influencia que pueda tener el clima en un dialecto establecido no se aplica para nada del paralelo 40°S al sur porque no ha habido tiempo para que el clima influencie consistentemente el dialecto.

Answer (score 1):

Según el catedrático de Lengua [José María Pérez Orozco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_P%C3%A9rez_Orozco), es el clima lo que puede determinar la evolución de un lenguaje. Obviamente, la altitud puede favorecer (o dejar de hacerlo) un buen clima, se entiende que a nivel del mar el clima es más suave que en zonas de montaña, pero sería un rasgo indirecto.

Lo siguiente [lo decía](https://www.codigonuevo.com/sociedad/reportaje-andaluces) el mencionado catedrático sobre el andaluz, un dialecto que comparte con el caribeño ese rasgo de omitir las *s* finales:

> El clima que influye mucho en la civilización, es decir nuestro pueblo tiene un clima que nos da lugar a hacer mucha parte de nuestra vida en la calle o en sitios de reunión que no son tu casa, nosotros estamos prácticamente continuamente charlando, reunidos. El uso de la lengua la va pulimentando, la va adaptando a nuestras necesidades, por eso aquí debido a el más y mayor uso de la lengua es por lo que la lengua ha ido avanzando.

Esta postura defiende, de hecho, que el andaluz no es más que un castellano más evolucionado, porque se encuentra más lejos del latín y es más eficaz, ya que dice más con menos:

> Una efectividad que lo que hace es emplear menos elementos en expresar lo que tú quieres decir. En dos horas el que está hablando un andaluz, le da más tiempo a decir más cosas que si estás hablando en correcto castellano. Y si tú dices mira 'no pasó na de na' y 'no ha pasado nada de nada', no es lo mismo.

Todo esto que se dice del andaluz se puede aplicar a la región del Caribe, conocida precisamente por su buen clima.

Comment: Tal como apunta la respuesta de @walen, habría que citar buena parte de Chile y Argentina como contraejemplos de clima caribeño (que, sin embargo, pueden haber heredado esta característica de los colonizadores andaluces?)